# How to create a recursive counter to find out how many parents and children have an element?

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have 2 tables.
Table with reletions and table with deals.
In my table of deals I have a list of DealID's and for them I have to find out how many parents or children they have

The scripts are here:
https://dbfiddle.uk/ZM9fuv7C

Ultimately I have to get this result

| DealID | ParentCNT | ChildCNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 106 | 2 | 1 |
| 107 | 1 | 2 |
| 108 | 2 | 0 |
| 109 | 0 | 0 |

````
WITH rec4 (ParentID, ChildID)
AS 
(
    SELECT ParentID, ChildID
    FROM t_parent 
 -- where ChildID = 106
    UNION ALL
    SELECT p.ParentID, p.ChildID
    FROM t_parent AS p
        JOIN rec4 AS r ON p.ParentID = r.ChildID

), rec5 (ParentID, ChildID)
AS 
(
    SELECT ParentID, ChildID
    FROM t_parent 
 -- where ChildID = 106
    UNION ALL
    SELECT p.ParentID, p.ChildID
    FROM t_parent AS p
        JOIN rec5 AS r ON p.ChildID = r.ParentID
)
--select ISNULL(a.DealID, 0), ttt.ParentCNT, ttt.ChildCNT
  --from #A a left join
  select ch.ParentID, ChildCNT, ParentCNT from (
select ParentID, COUNT(r5.ChildID) as ChildCNT from rec5 r5 Group by ParentID) ch
join (select ChildID, COUNT(r4.ParentID) as ParentCNT from rec4 r4 Group by ChildID) pr
on ch.ParentID = pr.ChildID--) ttt
--on a.DealID = ttt.ParentID```
````

Comment: Are you using `MySQL` or `SQL Server`?

Comment: @Squirrel
SQL Server

Comment: please update the tag accordingly

Comment: Also add your sample data to the question. Don't get me wrong, having a fiddle is great, but the question still needs to be self contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using two distinct recursive CTEs (one for the children, and the other for the parents) looks like a relevant approach.. Then we can `full join` them, aggregate and count:

```
with 
    children as (
        select parentid as dealid, parentid, childid from t_parent
        union all
        select r.dealid, p.parentid, p.childid
        from children r
        inner join t_parent p on p.parentid = r.childid
    ),
    parents as (
        select childid as dealid, parentid, childid from t_parent
        union all
        select r.dealid, p.parentid, p.childid
        from parents r
        inner join t_parent p on p.childid = r.parentid
    )
select coalesce(c.dealid, p.dealid) as dealid,
    count(distinct p.parentid) as parent_cnt,
    count(distinct c.childid)  as child_cnt
from children c
full join parents p on p.dealid = c.dealid
group by coalesce(c.dealid, p.dealid)
```

| dealid | parent_cnt | child_cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 0 | 3 |
| 102 | 0 | 2 |
| 103 | 1 | 2 |
| 104 | 0 | 3 |
| 105 | 1 | 1 |
| 106 | 2 | 1 |
| 107 | 1 | 2 |
| 108 | 2 | 0 |
| 110 | 3 | 0 |
| 111 | 2 | 1 |
| 112 | 3 | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oH9me8Sz)

I am not sure which logic you want to filter out records in the final resultset ; you might want to add a `where` clause to the outer `select`.